# Is the U2's 74,000 ft the highest a turbofan plane ever has gone?

Tags: turbofan, altitude, lockheed-u2, zoom-climb

What is the altitude record for a turbofan? The (usually) turbofan-powered U2 has gone to 74,000 ft (22.6 km) MSL, but did any turbofan plane surpass that, in a zoom climb for instance and with afterburners' help?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/45781/can-high-bypass-turbofans-cruise-at-high-altitude

Comment: The SR-71 goes higher, but its engines are in ramjet mode.

Comment: @JohnK Yes and it's a turbojet and ramjet, my question is about turbofans (some bypass ratio above 0).

Comment: To have a bypass ratio above 0 you need to have more air than you need in the combustion chamber. That's why you can afford to let air "bypass". This is far from true at that altitude.

Comment: @user3528438 Most U2s have turbofans. A high altitude can be achieved on an afterburner as well (if the plane has any, the U2 doesn't), and eventually with engines shut off, being carried by momentum to apogee.

Comment: mig 31 foxhounds regularly do 80,000 ft+ with a low bypass turbofan

Comment: @Mridul: Feel free to make that an answer.

Answer (score 5):

No.

In 1975, the F-15A *Streak Eagle*, propelled by 2 afterburning turbofans, [climbed to 98,425 feet in 3½ minutes](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/197972/mcdonnell-douglas-f-15-streak-eagle/), coasting nearly up to an altitude of 103,000 feet.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely certain where you have your information from. The U2's service ceiling was 70.000 feet and I can't find any reports about it going higher.

The F-104 mentioned in @bjelleklangs answer uses a turbojet engine so that disqualifies it from your question. The F-15A Streak Eagle mentioned in @Bob Mathews answer would be a valid contender but I want to mention the McDonnell Douglas F-4 Phantom, which had turbofan variants for the Royal Navy and the Royal Air Force and reached an official maximum height off 98.557 feet a tad bit higher than the F-15. Most likely not with the correct variant though.

Both these planes definitely used afterburners. The highest altitude ever reached by a plane simply powered by a propeller, which is a category I would put turboprops under, without an afterburner was NASA's Helios HP01 at 96.863 feet.

Comment: The F-4 is a contender, but I was correct in using “streak” vice “strike”. The F-15 Strike Eagle is a completely different variant of the F-15 — the “E” model. The F-15 Streak Eagle was a specially-configured F-15A, and is the only jet with the name “Streak Eagle”. There were 513 “Strike Eagle” jets built.

Comment: @BobMathews You indeed were, my bad

Comment: No big deal. I had actually forgotten about the difference myself until I started looking at old articles about the Streak Eagle and the team of pilots who flew the record-breaking flights.

Comment: What's posted here are basically comments on other posts, a discussion in other words, and not an answer to the stated question.

Comment: I disagree with other answers and then supply additional information that answers the question. How is that not an answer?